# HK2 and Impls with constructor arguments

Tags: java, jersey, hk2

I'm using HK2 as part of a Jersey RESTful API. I'm working in an multitenant system, and in most of my API calls, the tenant is a path parameter. I also have several DAOs, which currently accept the tenantId in their constructor, such as:

```
public final class WidgetMapper {
    public WidgetMapper(final int tenantId) { .. }
    ..
}
```

I'd like to use HK2 to provide my DAOs to the other layers of my application. What's the right way to do this?

1. Change the DAOs to use a setter rather than a constructor argument. Only .. ick. The `tenantId` is part of the required state of the DAO.
2. Add a layer of abstraction. Create `<interface>MapperFactory` and `MapperFactoryImpl`, which has a no-arg constructor and a bunch of getters, such as `getWidgetMapper` and `getGizmoMapper`. Only .. this seems cumbersome. I'd rather not have to maintain these extra classes.
3. Is there some magic way for HK2 to inject that int value into the WidgetMapper constructor at runtime? Then I could inject the tenantId into the mapper, and the mapper into my other classes.
4. ?? Other HK2 magic?

Answer (score 4):

You need to extract the tenant ID from the path parameter in the request, so as long as it's OK to instantiate your DAOs for each request, you can implement a `Factory`.

```
public WidgetMapperFactory implements Factory<WidgetMapper> {

    private final ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;

    @Inject
    public WidgetMapperFactory(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        this.containerRequestContext = containerRequestContext;
    }

    public WidgetMapper provide() {
        UriInfo uriInfo = containerRequestContext.getUriInfo();
        List<String> matchedUris = uriInfo.getMatchedURIs();
        int tenantId = 1; // Actually work it out from the matched URIs
        return new WidgetMapper(tenantId);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        // Do any clean up you need
    }

}
```

Then bind the factory:

```
public MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyResourceConfig() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(WidgetMapperFactory.class).to(WidgetMapper.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You can then inject `WidgetMapper` in a `Resource` class, and the `WidgetMapper` doesn't have any knowledge it's being used in a web service.

Answer (score 0):

> Change the DAOs to use a setter rather than a constructor argument.
>   Only .. ick. The tenantId is part of the required state of the DAO.

If your DAOs are singletons I don't see how this would work (or at least how it could be done cleanly).

> What's the right way to do this?

IMO, I think the best approach is to have 1) singleton DAOs 2) some type of proxy that got injected into the DAOs when they were instantiated by HK2 and then provided the correct tenant id for the current thread.

I can think of two ways to do this:

**Option 1:**

*I haven't tried it*, but I think you could *probably* inject UriInfo into your DAOs, either through the constructor, a private field, or setter.  You could extract the tenant id for the current request from the UriInfo instance.

If I were you, I'd create an abstract class for my DAOs that got a UriInfo injected into a private field.  I'd then provide a protected method to return the current tenant id from [uriInfo.getPathParameters](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathParameters%28%29)

```
public abstract class AbstractDao {

    // jersey/hk2 provides a proxy that references the current thread-bound request
    @Context
    private UriInfo info;

    protected int getTenantId()
    {
        // always returns the tenant id for the current request.  TODO: add
        // logic to handle calls that don't have a tenant id.
        return Integer.valueOf(info.getPathParameters.getFirst("tenantId");
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

> ?? Other HK2 magic?

You could write a [custom injection resolver](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html#d0e14465).

One more idea...

**Option 3:**

This one doesn't directly answer your question since it doesn't use HK2 to inject the tenant ID into the DAOs but I think it's worth mentioning.

You could implement your own [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) that obtained the tenant id and provided it to other components in your app.

By default, Jersey will invoke the filter after it resolves the resource method but before the method is actually invoked.  You can obtain a UriInfo from the [ContainerRequestContext](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html), get the tenant id path param, then stuff that param into your own thread local variable.  You could then reference the thread local within your DAO.  Again, I recommend adding a protected method in a base DAO class to encapsulate this logic.

> in most of my API calls, the tenant is a path parameter

Optionally, you can use [NameBinding](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) to control the behavior described above.

If you wanted to, you could implement option 3 using a regular ServletFilter instead.

**Note:**

After I wrote this answer, I realized that I assumed you were comfortable extending [ResourceConfig](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html), that you knew how to obtain an instance of [ServiceLocator](https://hk2.java.net/nonav/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.html), and that you were [comfortable with adding your own bindings](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/api.html#Binding_a_Descriptor_into_a_ServiceLocator).  If you're not, let me know and I'll edit my answer to provide more details.

Comment: John, thanks for the reply. The DAOs are not singletons and won't be singletons unless you can provide a compelling case for doing so. Option 1 is no good because the data access layer shouldn't know or care that it's serving a web API. Option 3 is the multithreading equivalent of all the layers sharing a static variable. I guess I could do that. Option 2 might work .. I'm poking around at it now. If that's what I go with, I'll mark as correct and upvote. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds like option 2 is the best.  You'd probably need to wrap your tenant id in a TenantIdentifier class.  Try doing that and then writing a `Factory<TenantIdentifier>` and an AbstractBinder that binds TenantIdentifier to the factory.  After you register the binder, you should be able to @Inject instances of TenantIdentifier.

Comment: Eric, any luck with option 2?  Curious how you solved this issue because I'm doing something similar in my project.